# Linker error with make file when using OpenGL functions

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, linker-errors, glut

I am having some trouble with using the openGL library in my program. First of all, I did implement all the relevant stuff correctly:

```
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```

And, in this program of mine, where I am tasked to draw out a bunch of rectangles, I encounter some problems when compiling. This is the error message when I compile with my make file:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_glBegin", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glClear", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
      display() in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glClearColor", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glColor3f", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glEnd", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glFlush", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
      display() in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glLineWidth", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glLoadIdentity", referenced from:
      display() in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glMatrixMode", referenced from:
      display() in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glScalef", referenced from:
      display() in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glTranslatef", referenced from:
      display() in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glVertex2i", referenced from:
      drawRegionsRec(treeNode*) in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutDisplayFunc", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutInit", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutInitDisplayMode", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutInitWindowPosition", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutInitWindowSize", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
  "_glutMainLoop", referenced from:
      _main in mondrian-a92186.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mondrian] Error 1
```

Essentially, what happens is every OpenGL function I call is just unrecognized and then I get a linker error.

I made sure that my makefile is also correct.

```
PLATFORM = $(shell uname)


## Compilation flags
##comment out one or the other 
##debugging 
CFLAGS = -g 
##release
#CFLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG
LDFLAGS=

CFLAGS+= -Wall

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),Darwin)
## Mac OS X
CFLAGS += -m64  -Wno-deprecated
INCLUDEPATH=-I/system/usr/local/include 
LDFLAGS+= -m64 -lc -framework AGL -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -framework Foundation
else
## Linux
CFLAGS += -m64
INCLUDEPATH  = -I/usr/include/GL/ 
LIBPATH = -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib
LDFLAGS+=  -lGL -lglut -lrt -lGLU -lX11 -lm  -lXmu -lXext -lXi
endif


CC = g++ -O3 -Wall $(INCLUDEPATH)


PROGS = mondrian

default: $(PROGS)

mondrian: mondrian.o geom.o rtimer.o
    $(CC) -o $@ mondrian.o geom.o rtimer.o $(LDFLAGS)

mondrian.o: mondrian.cpp  geom.h rtimer.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS)   mondrian.cpp  -o $@
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: First, the errors you're talking about here are _linker_ errors, so your comment _implement all the relevant stuff correctly_ showing include lines etc. is irrelevant to this problem; header files are used by the compiler not the linker.

Comment: Second, when reporting errors please show the linker command line that was invoked, not just the errors.  If you get linker errors then it's highly likely that the linker command line was wrong, and if you show it to us it's much simpler to see the problem.  For example, in your makefile you have linker commands for both MacOS and Linux but nowhere in your question do you tell us whether you're running on MacOS or on Linux, so we don't know which linker command will be used.

Comment: And finally, it's clear from the errors that they are not generated from the makefile you show because they say: `... in mondrian-a92186.o ...` but there's no `mondrian-a92186` in the makefile you've shown us.